# Modal inside another modal, on multiple modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I'm just trying to learn alittle about programming, but i've run into a problem.
The problem is trying to get multiple modals inside a modal on multiple modals, if that makes sense.

https://jsfiddle.net/cameLadv/5/

```js
var modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".button")];
modalBtns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var modal = btn.getAttribute('data-modal');
    document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
  }
});

var closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
closeBtns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var modal = btn.closest('.modal');
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.className === "modal") {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var ladom = document.getElementById('myA');


var a = document.getElementById("kobAtag");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("atagclose")[0];

a.onclick = function() {
    ladom.style.display = "block";
}


span.onclick = function() {
    ladom.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == ladom) {
        ladom.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
header {
 width:100%;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 
}



body {
 font-family: arial;
 margin:0px;
 width:100%;
}






.row1{
 float:center;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 350px;
}





.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 8888;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10vh auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 100%;
   

}
@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10vh auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 90%; 

    }
}


.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.button {
    background:none;
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  border-left:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  font-size:16px;
}



button {
    margin:0;
}



@media  {
  .modal-content p {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin:0px;
    left:700px;
    bottom:500px;
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;

    }
}

@media(min-width: 500px) {
 .modal-content img {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin:0px;
  position:relative;
  left:40px;
 }
}

@media{
 .modal-content h1{
    margin:0px;
    left:1500px;
    bottom:50px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;


 }
}
@media{
 .modal-content a:hover{
  color:grey;

 }
}

@media{
 .modal-content a{
  color:grey;
  text-decoration:none;

 }
}

@media{
 .modal-content h2{
    margin:0px;
    left:1470px;
    bottom:50px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;


 }

@media{
 .modal-content h3 {
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-left:35px;
 }

.købting  {
 margin:0;
 padding-left:450px;

}


.kob {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.kob-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; 
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; 
}


.kobclose {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.kobclose:hover,
.kobclose:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.atag {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}


.atag-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; 
}


.atagclose {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.atagclose:hover,
.atagclose:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>


 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mgstyle.css">
 <title>Marias Galleri</title>
</head>



<body>
 


<div class="row1">

  <button class="button" data-modal="modalOne">
   one
  </button>


  <button class="button" data-modal="modalTwo">
    two
  </button>




  <button class="button" data-modal="modalThree">
    three
  </button>


<div id="modalOne" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <a class="close">&times;</a>
       
      <div class="flub">
       <h3>Title om billedet</h3>
      <img src="images/one.png">
      
      <p>Words about the picture, Words about the picture, </p>
      <div class="pris"><h2> Pris 500 </h2></div>

      <a id="kobAtag"><h1> open second modal</h1></a>
      <div id="myA" class="atag" data-modal="kobmodal">
         <div class="atag-content">
          <span class="atagclose">&times;</span>
          <h3> THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, </h3>
        </div>
        <script src="scriptbok.js"></script>
      </div>





        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modalTwo" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
             <h3>Title om billedet</h3>
      <img src="images/two.png">
    <p>Words about the picture, Words about the picture, </p>
       <div class="pris"><h2> Pris 500 </h2></div>
      <a id="kobAtag"><h1> open second modal</h1></a>
      <div id="myA" class="atag" data-modal="kobmodal">
         <div class="atag-content">
          <span class="atagclose">&times;</span>
          <h3> THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, </h3>
        </div>
        <script src="scriptbok.js"></script>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modalThree" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
             <h3>Title om billedet</h3>
      <img src="images/three.png">
      <p>Words about the picture, Words about the picture, </p>
      <div class="pris"><h2> Pris 500 </h2></div>
      <a id="kobAtag"><h1>open second modal</h1></a>
      <div id="myA" class="atag" data-modal="kobmodal">
         <div class="atag-content">
          <span class="atagclose">&times;</span>
          <h3> THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, THIS SHOULD WORK, </h3>
        </div>
        <script src="scriptbok.js"></script>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</div>




</div>


</body>



</html>
```

The open second modal is kinda off screen so you might have to zoom out - sorry im a noob.
The second modal works in the "one" first modal, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem... What is happening and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: The expected behavior is to have a modal that opens inside the modals,

Comment: Part of your question may be more about design patterns. Check out this question and answer for some guidance. I feel like modals on top of modals can be a red flag https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52042/is-it-acceptable-to-open-a-modal-popup-on-top-of-another-modal-popup

Comment: This was mainly just to learn how to make it work :)

Comment: At first glance it looks like you've missed a closing `}` on one of your `@media` bits